# How to change Adb port on AOSP from 5555 to something else

Tags: android, adb, android-source

I am developing an Android ROM for a custom board. The requirements for the project state that we need to enable Adb over TCP so the customer can connect remotely to the devices and debug/install applications. However, the customer has asked that the default port (5555) be changed to another value (in this case 4848).

I have looked at the AOSP source code but I am not able to find where this is set. I'm probably missing it, but I have looked into the core system repository and have not found the required value. Anyone able to help?

Thank you in advance for the kind help,

Lorenzo

Comment: In this thread he mentions configuring this property in the build.prop: https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/67916/is-it-possible-to-adb-connect-android-via-wifi-without-configuring-port-on-andro

Comment: Thank you @ninehundreds. That was exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use adb-tools

if you have root authority:

```
adb -d shell setprop persist.adb.tcp.port 4848
```

else:

```
adb -d shell setprop service.adb.tcp.port 4848
```